# Roots of a transcendental equation with unknown a complex number

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

I am trying to solve a problem and I got stuck with a complicated transcendental equation. I intend to find these roots. Here, $\omega$ is a complex number, whose imaginary part can be positive or negative. $k$ is a positive real number. I am using `FindRoot` but the issue is I don't know how to change the guesses with increasing $k$. So, it might fail if I keep on increasing $k$ but keep the guess unchanged.
Please help me. The code is attached below.

```
θ = 89 Pi/180;
me = 1;
mi = 1836 me;
Ti = Te = 1;
ve = Sqrt[1/me];
vi = Sqrt[1/mi];
ce = -1;
ci = -ce;
ωce = -1;
ωci = 1/1836 Abs[ωce]; 
ne = 10^2 ωce^2 me;
ni = 1836 ne;
ωpe = 10 Abs[ωce];
ωpi = ωpe;
ke = Sqrt[ne];
ki = Sqrt[ni];
ae = Sqrt[1/me] 1/(10 ωce);
ai = vi/ωci;
ky[k_] = k Cos[θ];
kz[k_] = k Sin[θ];
ϵn = 0.001;
g = ϵn ;
vge = g/ωce;
vgi = g/ωci;
vni = vi^2 ϵn/ωci;
vne = ve^2 ϵn/ωce;
λi[k_] = ky[k]^2 ai^2;
λe[k_] = ky[k]^2 ae^2;


 ζ11e[m_, k_] = 
  Simplify[((ω - ky[k] vge + 
       me ωce )/(Sqrt[2] kz[k] ve))];
ζ11i[m_, k_] = 
  Simplify[((ω - ky[k] vgi + 
       mi ωci )/(Sqrt[2] kz[k] vi))];


disi[m_, k_] = 
  2 I Exp[-ζ11i[m, k]^(2 m)] Integrate[
    Exp[-t^2], {t, -Infinity, ζ11i[m, k]}];
dise[m_, k_] = 
  2 I Exp[-ζ11e[m, k]^(2 m)] Integrate[
    Exp[-t^2], {t, -Infinity, ζ11e[m, k]}];


Ke[k_, ω_] = 
  Simplify[((ke^2/
       k^2) (1 - (ω - 
          ky[k] (vne + vge)) Exp[-λe[k]]/(Sqrt[2] kz[
            k] ve) Sum[
         BesselI[m, λe[k]] dise[m, k], {m, 0, 
          0}] - ω ϵn/(ky[k] kz[k] ve Sqrt[
            2]) Exp[-λe[k]] Sum[
         m BesselI[m, λe[k]] ζ11e[m, k], {m, 0, 0}]))];
Ki[k_, ω_] = 
  Simplify[((ki^2/
       k^2) (1 - (ω - 
          ky[k] (vni + vgi)) Exp[-λi[k]]/(Sqrt[2] kz[
            k] vi) Sum[
         BesselI[m, λi[k]] disi[m, k], {m, 0, 
          0}] - ω ϵn/(ky[k] kz[k] vi Sqrt[
            2]) Exp[-λi[k]] Sum[
         m BesselI[m, λi[k]] ζ11i[m, k], {m, 0, 0}]))];





s1[k_, ω_] 
:=(*Simplify[1+Kj[κ,ω1]//Rationalize];*)
 1 + Ki[k, ω] + Ke[k, ω]


tab = Table[ω /. 
    FindRoot[
     s1[k, ω] == 
      0, {ω, -0.01 + 0.01 ϵn g I}], {k, 0.01, 40}];
```

Comment: Is it possible to show a simpler example of what you are after?

Comment: @rhermans Yeah I would think so. The resultant equation contains exponential and error functions.

Comment: @rhermans It also has modified Bessel function of the first kind. So, something involving these functions but simpler than the above equation would also be useful